# Rendering sections in flatlist/sectionlist from one data set

Tags: react-native

I have some JSON data that looks like this:

```
{
  "distance":"1",
  "name":"whatever",
  "listPriority":"1",
}
```

I'm passing this into a `Flatlist`:

```
<FlatList
                    key={'my-list'}
                    data={JSON}
                    renderItem={this.renderCard}
                    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
                />
```

What I want to do is section off the data based on list priority, so all items with a value for listPriority key of 1 would show under my section header that says "These are items for 1", and a value of listPriority key of 2 would have a section header that says "Section header 2", and so forth.

I.e. resulting in something like this:

### List Priority 1

- item in the list
- item in the list

### List Priority 2

- item in the list
- item in the list

### List Priority 3

- item in the list
- item in the list

**How can I get sections into my `Flatlist`?**

`Sectionlist` seems to be only if you are passing in separate data sets for each manually entered section.

Comment: Perhaps you could order/group the input data before passing it to `<FlatList>`?

Comment: @DacreDenny That's plan B. Just seems like overkill if there's a basic functionality I'm missing in these components.

Comment: Yeah understand that - I think that'll be your best bet though. Let me know if you need help with the code for that

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that you could use the SectionList component, that would give you the headers and (if you want) them being sticky, which is a nice to have behaviour. 
So you just need to create an array of objects that follow the needed format for the component to work properly.

```
<SectionList
  renderItem={({item}) => someFunctionHere(item)/<SomeComponent item={item}>}
  sections={sections}
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
/>
```

Define `sections` to be an array of format:

```
[
  { 
    title: "List priority 1", 
    data: [{"distance":"1", "listPriority": "1"...}, ...]
  },
  { 
    title: "List priority 2", 
    data: [{"distance":"20", "listPriority": "2"...}, ...]
  },
  ...
]
```

So again, just format your data (most probably within the `componentDidMount` hook) and when then data is formatted you can include it into the state and eventually feeding it into the `SectionList` component so that it will re-render